# Download hive query to csv format using beeline command

Tags: hadoop, hive, beeline

I need to download hive query result to local file path in csv format. Additionally, column values should be enclosed in quotes, fields are terminated by comma and file should have column headers in the first row.

Can anyone help me with best approach to achieve this? Note - Query usually returns more than 5M rows.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to create a hive table with your selected data as below.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ramesh_csv (col1 INT, col2 STRING)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
"separatorChar" = ",",
"quoteChar" = "\""
)
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 'mylocation';

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE ramesh_csv VALUES (1, 'TEST'), (2, 'TEST AGAIN');
```

In your case, you will insert your selected records into the table.

Now get the HDFS file created. That will be comma separated with double quotes enclosed.

See my output below

```
"1","TEST"
"2","TEST AGAIN"
```

And you can use `hdfs -getmerge hdfs://mylocation data.csv` to download the hdfs part files into a single local file